# Docker Container (Django Server) not accessible from local machine

Tags: python, docker

I'm trying to run a simple container from a custom Dockerfile, but cannot access it when I go to my localhost. Anyone know why this could be? Here is the Dockerfile:

```
FROM python:3.7.7-buster

RUN curl -sS https://dl.yarnpkg.com/debian/pubkey.gpg | apt-key add -
RUN echo deb "https://dl.yarnpkg.com/debian/ stable main" | tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/yarn.list
RUN apt-get update
RUN yes | apt-get install npm
RUN yes | apt-get install yarn

COPY . .
RUN ./build.sh

EXPOSE 8000
CMD gunicorn -b 127.0.0.1:8000 project_config.wsgi.prod:application
```

And I use the following command to start the server:

```
docker run -p 8000:8000 -e SECRET_KEY=supersecretkey mycontainer
```

I can see the server is running fine but when I got to localhost port 8000, I get nothing. Any help appreciated!

Comment: Change the `gunicorn -b` address to `0.0.0.0:8000`: setting a bind address to 127.0.0.1 means "make it unreachable from outside this container".